# Get duplicated elements in a list without using (Ord a)

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to make a function that concatenates a list of lists, sorts it, and gives back the duplicated values.

The issue I'm facing is that it tells me to change (Eq a) to (Ord a) for the last function, but I cannot do this. How can I solve this without changing (Eq a) to (Ord a) ?

This is the code I have:

```
group                   :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
group                   =  groupBy (==)

groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _  []           =  []
groupBy eq (x:xs)       =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
                           where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
uniq :: Eq b => [b] -> [b]
uniq = map head . group

insert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert x [] = [x]
insert x (y:ys) | x < y     = x:y:ys
                | otherwise = y:(insert x ys)

isort :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
isort [] = []
isort (x:xs) = insert x (isort xs)

kms :: Ord a => [a]
kms xss = uniq (isort (concat xss))

pairwiseIntersections :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
pairwiseIntersections xss = kms xss
```

Comment: You can't sort without `Ord` or something equivalent to it. In order to sort, you have to be able to tell which items go in front of which. To compare the items. In the absence of a way to compare, the concept of sorting is meaningless.

Comment: Your last function calls function `kms` which already has an `Ord a` constraint. I am afraid this constraint gets propagated upwards then.

Comment: If you can only use `Eq a`, you need a different algorithm to find duplicates. Essentially, you need to compare (with `==` only) each element in the list to the elements after that. This is less efficient than sorting, but it's essentially the only option.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot sort a list without its elements having some ordering -- meaning that they must be instances of `Ord`.

You can do other things to deduplicate a list, like `nub`, but if you want it sorted you need `Ord` or an equivalent ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You mention no complexity requirements, so the simplest approach could be

```
keepOnlyDups [] = []
keepOnlyDups (x:xs) = [x | elem x xs] ++ keepOnlyDups [ y | y <- xs, y /= x]

removeExtras [] = []
removeExtras (x:xs) = [x] ++ removeExtras [ y | y <- xs, y /= x]
```

answering both your question's text and the implied meaning of the code.

Implementing `keepOnlyUniques` is left as an exercise, if you're interested in that.